# Warp any collection into a map

Tags: java, collections

I want to implement an interface that allow me to create a map from any collections with the following default method:

```java
    default <T_KEY> Map<T_KEY, T_ELEM> toMap(final Function<T_ELEM, T_KEY> getKey)
```

`getKey` return a map key for a given `T_ELEM`.

It should be called like this:

```java
Map<String, String> values = ExtCollection.of(list).toMap(it -> it.substring(0, 3));
```

How can I retrieve the collection to workaround with ?

Comment: I miss the collection as a parameter like this: `default <T_KEY> Map<T_KEY, T_ELEM> toMap(Collection<T_ELEM> collection, final Function<T_ELEM, T_KEY> getKey)`

Comment: The idea between all of these is to call it like that: `Map<String, String> values = ExtCollection.of(list).toMap(it -> it.substring(0, 3));` where `ExtCollection` is my interface

Comment: Is there any further functionality to `ExtCollection`? Otherwise why not just `ExtCollection.toMap(...)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API `ExtCollection.of(list).toMap` needs to keep a reference to the collection, because of that you cann't implement it as an interface only.
This is an implementation with a plain class:

```
public class ExtCollection<T_ELEM> {

    private Collection<T_ELEM> collection;

    private ExtCollection(Collection<T_ELEM> collection) {
        this.collection = collection;
    }

    public static <T_ELEM> ExtCollection<T_ELEM> of(Collection<T_ELEM> collection){
        return new ExtCollection<>(collection);
    }

    public <T_KEY> Map<T_KEY, T_ELEM> toMap(final Function<T_ELEM, T_KEY> getKey){
        return collection.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(getKey, Function.identity()));
    }
}
```

Also you can extends the interface but you will need to invoke a class inside to `ExtCollection.of` method.

```
public interface ExtCollection<T_ELEM> extends Collection<T_ELEM> {
    ...
    default <T_KEY> Map<T_KEY, T_ELEM> toMap(final Function<T_ELEM, T_KEY> getKey){
        return stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(getKey, Function.identity()));
    }

    static<T_ELEM>  ExtCollection<T_ELEM> of(Collection<T_ELEM> collection){
        return new ExtCollection<T_ELEM>() {
            ...
        };
    }
}
```